# Ruby On Rails Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I have seen two different ways of migrating a database.  Which one is the proper way to do it in Rails 3?

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :title

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

and

class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.column :name, :string
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

Thank You!

Comment: first one is the default, see when you scaffold

Comment: So what are the advantages of the second?

Comment: there are no advantages to the second

Comment: There's only a disadvantage to the second: it's less compact than the first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`t.string :title` is just a shortcut for `t.column :title, :string`

Both of them are ok, there is no discrimination. I'd normally prefer the short form, as it is more readable to me but it's just a matter of opinion.

Comment: +1 "Sexy Migrations" We're introduced at Railsconf 2007 I believe introducing Rails 2.something by David Heinemeier Hansson.  there is video footage where he covers this.
http://jroller.com/obie/entry/railsconf_2007_opening_keynote


It just keeps migrations a little more DRY.